# Creating union type to ensure each value of `enum` is handled

Tags: typescript, exhaustive

I have an enum of operations (that I can't change, unfortunately):

```js
enum OpType {
  OpA = 0,
  OpB = 1,
}
```

…and a set of types for objects that carry the data needed for each operation:

```js
type A = {
  readonly opType: OpType.OpA;
  readonly foo: number;
};

type B = {
  readonly opType: OpType.OpB;
  readonly bar: string;
};
```

…and finally a handler function that ensure that each operation is handled:

```js
type Ops = A | B;

export const ensureExhaustive = (_param: never) => {};

export const handleOp = (op: Ops) => {
  switch (op.opType) {
    case OpType.OpA:
      if (op.foo < 80) { /* … */ }
      break;
    case OpType.OpB:
      if (op.bar === 'foo') { /* … */ }
      break;
    default:
      ensureExhaustive(op);
  }
}
```

However, this `handleOp` function only really assures that we handle what was explicitly added to the Ops union – the connection to the `OpType` enum has been lost, so if a `OpC = 2` is added to the `enum`, it won't be detected that this isn't handled.

How can I “connect” the enum values (probably through an `Ops` type) to the `switch` statement in `handleOp` to ensure that each value is handled?

Comment: Sure, just use the same idea as your ensureExhaustive function: https://tsplay.dev/mbKOdW

Comment: Oh, and you can be even fancier and *reuse* the ensureExhaustive function: https://tsplay.dev/mAdAvN

Comment: @vera. This is fantastic! Thanks! It even makes sense (after staring at it for a while). If you make it an answer, I'll click the checkmark! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just recreate the `ensureExhaustive` function as a type:

```
type EnsureExhaustive<T extends never> = T;
```

Then you could define a dummy type that just makes sure something is `never`:

```
type OpsMatchesEnum = EnsureExhaustive<Exclude<OpType, Ops["opType"]>>;
```

Conveniently, there exists a utility `Exclude` that already has the behavior we want:

```
Exclude<1 | 2 | 3, 1 | 2>;     // 3
Exclude<1 | 2 | 3, 1 | 2 | 3>; // never
```

In other words, the result of this type is `never` if the second argument encompasses the first. Translating to our use case, we want this to be `never` if `Ops["opType"]` uses all members of `OpType`.

Another trick we can do is to make `ensureExhaustive` *generic*, so that it would have the signature

```
export const ensureExhaustive = <T extends never>(_param: T) => {};
```

so we can then utilize [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) that were introduced in 4.7, removing the need for an `EnsureExhaustive` type:

```
type OpsMatchesEnum = typeof ensureExhaustive<Exclude<OpType, Ops["opType"]>>;
```

Of course, if you have `noUnusedLocals` enabled or a linter, this dummy type might cause an error or warning.

- [Playground (EnsureExhaustive type)](https://tsplay.dev/mbKOdW)
- [Playground (instantiation expressions)](https://tsplay.dev/mAdAvN)