# Can typescript check every Record value of Enum?

Tags: typescript, frontend, record

Typescript is beautiful, and I love to write on typescript
cause I can just write

```
enum Test {
    some = 'some',
    another = 'another',
}

const test: Record<Test, string> = {
    some: 'string'
}
```

then typescript asks me to type every key value from `Test` as the key of my test object

> Property 'another' is missing in type '{ some: string; }' but required in type 'Record<Test, string>'

But if I want to write an opposite operation (like parse/stringify), I want to be sure that I don't miss some Test as values of Record

```
enum Test {
    some = 'some',
    another = 'another',
}
const test: Record<string, Test> = {
    some: Test.some
}
```

But typescript assume that it is correct.

I would like to throw some error by typescript.

Is there any way in typescript to check every Record value of Enum?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152029/creating-union-type-to-ensure-each-value-of-enum-is-handled/75174151#75174151) will inspire you.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6LR6m) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! It looks like exactly what I need. By the way, my question is don't need for parse/stringify task, I have some mistake. But the question is really curios, if you write up an answer explaining, probably, I'll pick the explanation as the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really have the idea of "exhaustive property types", but you could write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type along with a helper function to validate that a given value behaves as you like.  For example:

```
const exhaustive = <V,>() => <T extends Record<keyof T, V>>(
    t: { [K in keyof T]: [V] extends [T[keyof T]] ? T[K] : Exclude<V, T[keyof T]> }
) => t;
```

This is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function where you manually specify the value type `V` you'd like to "exhaust", and it outputs another generic function that does the check:

```
enum Test {
    some = 'some',
    another = 'another',
}   
const exhaustiveTest = exhaustive<Test>()
```

(The reason you need to use two functions like that is because TypeScript doesn't let you manually specify a generic type argument while inferring another one; there is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) and the various workarounds including currying are discussed in [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218))

---

When you call `exhaustiveTest()` it will return its input, but a compiler error will occur if you are missing any of the values in `Test`:

```
const test = exhaustiveTest({
    abc: Test.some,
    def: Test.another
}); // okay

const badTest = exhaustiveTest({
    abc: Test.some // error! Type 'Test.some' is not assignable to type 'Test.another'
})
```

Hooray, that's what you wanted!

---

The way it works is that the call to `exhaustiveTest()` infers the type argument `T` to be the type passed in as the function argument `t`, but it checks it against the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{ [K in keyof T]: [Test] extends [T[keyof T]] ? T[K] : Exclude<Test, T[keyof T]> }`.  Each property is the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `[Test] extends [T[keyof T]] ? T[K] : Exclude<Test, T[keyof T]>`.  That means: if every value of type `Test` can be assigned to one of the property types of `T`, then each property of `T` is just fine as itself (the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`); otherwise, it should be `Exclude<Test, T[keyof T]>` using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter out all the properties of `T` from `Test` to get just the missed values, so that the error message will mention these missing values.

As a concrete case, if `T` is `{abc: Test.some; def: Test.another}`, then `T[keyof T]` is `Test.some | Test.another`, which is the same as `Test`, and so the mapped type is just `{abc: Test.some; def: Test.another}`, and it type checks.  But if `T` is just `{abc: Test.some}`, then `T[keyof T]` is just `Test.some`, which is missing thing from `Test`.  And so the mapped type is `{abc: Test.another}`, and it fails to type check, complaining about the missing thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAsAKCtq8D2EwUAvFAOT6FkA0mOUAhiHogBbABOJ5TL7HNTAF9MmAMZ4QSKMAAerBmCQBLAG5FSAHgBq1AHwAKAJQk9UTTBmzEoACbwoAJWASOtzQGtgATzwAzWGoobT1DOhxEAC5UKABtAGkoZRAoL18AmABdaNjtTKsbEHs4mFi0-1hM-IB+WAT86IBRWTEAGzBbYB0g0vKMzLMRDBNiM0QAblEMCSlkOQUlRDVgOGlSecUVdQsEREMjKZnpGzWrBa2V3YN0LBwGACMxaNXEADpKYFpb7E6-Z93Xrw2JxhEZxlAAPQQqB4DwMbyHSTSe4MWwvbgbRbLF7XcLYB5PWAAj6Q6GcDh4DgAQlg3gADkQyC93gRgGQkg5mMgGPB4MoAOYgB6tIiIPBQRD0xnMoH8MigoA)