# Visitor pattern for number based enums

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to  use vistor pattern to make sure that all cases are handled when I add a new enum value. Enum example:

```
export enum ActionItemTypeEnum {
    AccountManager = 0,
    Affiliate = 4,
}
```

Currently, I'm using the following approach:

```
interface IActionItemTypeVisitor<T> {
    accountManager(value: ActionItemTypeEnum.AccountManager): T;
    affiliate(value: ActionItemTypeEnum.Affiliate): T;
}

// generates compiler error when case is missing:
const visitActionItemType = <T>(value: ActionItemTypeEnum, visitor: IActionItemTypeVisitor<T>) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    switch (value) {
        case ActionItemTypeEnum.None:
            return visitor.none(value);
        case ActionItemTypeEnum.AccountManager:
            return visitor.accountManager(value);
    }
};

// ActionItemPermissionVisitor implements IActionItemTypeVisitor<Permission>
const permission = visitActionItemType(this.type, new ActionItemPermissionVisitor())
```

I'm looking for a more idiomatic TypeScript solution if that exists.

---

This is final solution:

```
export type IActionItemTypeVisitor<T> = {
    [K in keyof typeof ActionItemTypeEnum as Uncapitalize<K>]: (value: (typeof ActionItemTypeEnum)[K]) => T;
};

export const visitActionItemType = <T>(value: ActionItemTypeEnum, visitor: IActionItemTypeVisitor<T>): T => {
    const key: string = ActionItemTypeEnum[value]?.[0].toLowerCase() + ActionItemTypeEnum[value]?.substring(1);
    return visitor[key]?.(value);
};

export class ActionItemVisitor implements IActionItemTypeVisitor<string> {
    public accountManager(value: ActionItemTypeEnum.AccountManager): string {
        return 'AccountManager';
    }

    public affiliate(value: ActionItemTypeEnum.Affiliate): string {
        return 'Affiliate';
    }
}

const result: string = visitActionItemType(ActionItemTypeEnum.AccountManager, new ActionItemVisitor());
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I want a more idiomatic TypeScript solution if that exists.

Comment: For starters, your example code given doesn't work in the playground. Your interface defines `accountManager`, but your code uses `visitor.AccountManager`, which doesn't exist. Similarly, you use `visitor.None`, which also doesn't exist on the interface. Could you fix these inconsistencies?

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? I think it is the best since it relies on the compiler to do the work, but you could always try something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75152029/18244921).

Comment: @vera. compiler works, no question, but each time I add a new enum value I have to modify visitor interface and visitor function, I suspect that it is possible to derive necessary types from the enum itself, so that I will only have to modify concrete visitors.

Comment: I suppose you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOxolN) but getting rid of that switch statement will be ugly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### TLDR; take a look to the following stackblitz example, there's more comments there:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqbtzd?file=src/main.ts

---

This can be done using [typescript advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html).

First you define away to obtain the expected method names, the following `type` will  modify it's parameter first letter to lowercase:

```js
type FirstLetterLowercase<S> = S extends `${infer C}${infer R}`
  ? `${Lowercase<C>}${R}`
  : never;
```

Then you need to get the current one to parse them using `FirstLetterLowercase`, note that `K in keyof typeof ActionItemTypeEnum` is used to obtain the enum name:

```js
type TActionItemTypeVisitor<T> = {
  [K in keyof typeof ActionItemTypeEnum as FirstLetterLowercase<K>]: (
    value: typeof ActionItemTypeEnum[K]
  ) => T;
};
```

Also, to get rid of your switch/case you can just call the function directly inside the `visitor` object:

```js
// doesn't generate compiler error when case is missing
visitActionItemType<T>(
value: ActionItemTypeEnum,
visitor: TActionItemTypeVisitor<T>
) {
  // note that this won't work with single letter enum values
  return visitor[ActionItemTypeEnum[value][0].toLowerCase() + ActionItemTypeEnum[value].substring(1)](value);
}
```

---

Thats's it... Later you can even implement your own interface using the declared type:

```js
interface IActionItemTypeVisitor
  extends TActionItemTypeVisitor<string[]> { // <-- this example show an `string[]` implementation
  specialMethodOnlyForStringArray: () => void;
}

...

/**
 * Demo implementation for `string[]`
 *
 * This one generates compiler error when method implementation is missing.
 */
export class ActionItemPermissionVisitor implements IActionItemTypeVisitor {
  none(value: ActionItemTypeEnum): string[] {
    return [];
  }
  accountManager(value: ActionItemTypeEnum) {
    return ['permission1', 'permission2'];
  }
  affiliate(value: ActionItemTypeEnum) {
    return ['permission3'];
  }
  // method just for demo
  specialMethodOnlyForStringArray() {
    console.log('do something special :)');
  }
}
...
this.permission = this.visitActionItemType(
  this.type,
  new ActionItemPermissionVisitor()
);
```

For example, if you add an enum value called `productManager` it'll throw the following error:
[image]

---

In case your were thinking about exact types, there's an open [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for Typescript language to do that; there's a an approach to solve it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-1412394955).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type IActionItemTypeVisitor<T> = { 
    [key in Uncapitalize<keyof typeof ActionItemTypeEnum>]: (value: ActionItemTypeEnum) => T;
};
```

This will trigger a warning when any enum case is missing, or when there's unrecognized entry.

Comment: This way compiler forces to use function properties instead of methods, is there any way to overcome it?